About a proof of the conditional Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
Prove the conditional Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: if $X, Y \in L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ is sub- $\sigma$-field, then
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X Y| \mid \mathcal{G}]^2 \leq \mathbb{E}\left[X^2 \mid \mathcal{G}\right] \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[Y^2 \mid \mathcal{G}\right] \text { a.s. }
$$
[Hint: Consider the (random) quadratic function $\alpha(t)=\mathbb{E}\left[(X+t Y)^2 \mid \mathcal{G}\right]$.]
I was a previous post that has solved the problem by a different approach (Proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for conditional expectations). But I just was wondering how it could proceed with the Hint considering the (random) quadratic function $\alpha(t)$.

Notice that $\alpha (t)\geq 0$ a.s..  Then, develop the square, and you'll have a polynomial of degree 2, that will be a.S.  always positive. That mean that the discriminant is a.s. negative... and the claim follows...

Or notice that as such $\inf_t \alpha(t) \ge 0$. Calculate the minimizer, and solve.

Thank you. I got it.
